# Error al instalar la librería pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy introduciéndome a pygame y a la hora de intalar pygame (`pip install pygame`) me sale este error:

```
Collecting pygame
  Downloading pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz (10.1 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.1/10.1 MB 979.9 kB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [77 lines of output]
     
     
      WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
      Using WINDOWS configuration...
     
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\SERGIO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5shrtwsh\pygame_81569199594247cf9c1f66b49027d9a3\setup.py", line 359, in <module>
          buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
        File "C:\Users\SERGIO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5shrtwsh\pygame_81569199594247cf9c1f66b49027d9a3\buildconfig\config.py", line 225, in main
          deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\SERGIO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5shrtwsh\pygame_81569199594247cf9c1f66b49027d9a3\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 511, in main        
          return setup_prebuilt_sdl2(prebuilt_dir)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\SERGIO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5shrtwsh\pygame_81569199594247cf9c1f66b49027d9a3\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 471, in setup_prebui
lt_sdl2
          DEPS.configure()
        File "C:\Users\SERGIO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5shrtwsh\pygame_81569199594247cf9c1f66b49027d9a3\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 336, in configure   
          from . import vstools
        File "C:\Users\SERGIO\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5shrtwsh\pygame_81569199594247cf9c1f66b49027d9a3\buildconfig\vstools.py", line 11, in <module>        
          compiler.initialize()
        File "D:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 403, in initialize
          vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "D:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 281, in query_vcvarsall
          raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
      distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
      Making dir :prebuilt_downloads:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip ed561079ec622b0bab5a9e02976f5d540b0622da
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip 137f86474691f4e12e76e07d58d5920c8d844d5b
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip 1436df41ebc47ac36e02ec9bda5699e80ff9bd27
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip 9097148f4529cf19f805ccd007618dec280f0ecc
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip:
      Downloading... https://www.pygame.org/ftp/jpegsr9d.zip ed10aa2b5a0fcfe74f8a6f7611aeb346b06a1f99
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\jpegsr9d.zip:
      Downloading... https://pygame.org/ftp/prebuilt-x64-pygame-1.9.2-20150922.zip 3a5af3427b3aa13a0aaf5c4cb08daaed341613ed
      Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\prebuilt-x64-pygame-1.9.2-20150922.zip:
      copying into .\prebuilt-x64
      Path for SDL: prebuilt-x64\SDL2-2.0.18
      ...Library directory for SDL: prebuilt-x64/SDL2-2.0.18/lib/x64
      ...Include directory for SDL: prebuilt-x64/SDL2-2.0.18/include
      Path for FONT: prebuilt-x64\SDL2_ttf-2.0.15
      ...Library directory for FONT: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_ttf-2.0.15/lib/x64
      ...Include directory for FONT: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_ttf-2.0.15/include
      Path for IMAGE: prebuilt-x64\SDL2_image-2.0.5
      ...Library directory for IMAGE: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_image-2.0.5/lib/x64
      ...Include directory for IMAGE: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_image-2.0.5/include
      Path for MIXER: prebuilt-x64\SDL2_mixer-2.0.4
      ...Library directory for MIXER: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/lib/x64
      ...Include directory for MIXER: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/include
      Path for PORTMIDI: prebuilt-x64
      ...Library directory for PORTMIDI: prebuilt-x64/lib
      ...Include directory for PORTMIDI: prebuilt-x64/include
      DLL for SDL2: prebuilt-x64/SDL2-2.0.18/lib/x64/SDL2.dll
      DLL for SDL2_ttf: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_ttf-2.0.15/lib/x64/SDL2_ttf.dll
      DLL for SDL2_image: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_image-2.0.5/lib/x64/SDL2_image.dll
      DLL for SDL2_mixer: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_mixer-2.0.4/lib/x64/SDL2_mixer.dll
      DLL for portmidi: prebuilt-x64/lib/portmidi.dll
      Path for FREETYPE not found.
      ...Found include dir but no library dir in prebuilt-x64.
      Path for PNG not found.
      ...Found include dir but no library dir in prebuilt-x64.
      Path for JPEG not found.
      ...Found include dir but no library dir in prebuilt-x64.
      DLL for freetype: prebuilt-x64/SDL2_ttf-2.0.15/lib/x64/libfreetype-6.dll
     
      ---
      For help with compilation see:
          https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
      To contribute to pygame development see:
          https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
      ---
     
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Hay una forma de solucionarlo??

Comment: Versión de python?

Comment: Según los logs de la instalación esta fallando al tratar de encontrar la librería vcvarsall.bat que se instala con el Microsoft Visual Studio Compiler prueba reinstalando o verificar la instrucciones https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows